# loading data into datagridview from List<> customerlist

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need help populating a `DataGridView`. When I debug I can see that it has records, but they are not shown in the `DataGridView`. Here is my code (mind you I am a newbie in C#):

```
private void listCustomer_Frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView custDGV = new DataGridView();
    customerList = CustomerDB.GetListCustomer();
    custDGV.DataSource = customerList;
    cm = (CurrencyManager)custDGV.BindingContext[customerList];
    cm.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the DataGridView at function scope and you never add it to any container. Since nothing has a reference to it, it disappears as soon as the function exits.

You need to do something like this:

```
this.Controls.Add(custDGV); // add the grid to the form so it will actually display
```

Before the function finishes. Like this:

```
private void listCustomer_Frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView custDGV = new DataGridView();
    this.Controls.Add(custDGV); // add the grid to the form so it will actually display
    customerList = CustomerDB.GetListCustomer();
    custDGV.DataSource = customerList;
    cm = (CurrencyManager)custDGV.BindingContext[customerList];
    cm.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Either that, or perhaps @Salsero has a DataGridView in a Form somewhere already, and just needs to populate that instead of creating a new one